# React native password show hide

Tags: react-native

I need to show hide my password on eye click.

Right now I am trying to do like this

```
const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false)

<View style={styles.SectionStyle}>
  <Text style={styles.textStyle} >Password</Text>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.inputStyle}
      onChangeText={password => setPassword(password)}
      underlineColorAndroid="#FFFFFF"
      placeholderTextColor="grey"
      secureTextEntry={showPassword}
      placeholder="Must be at least 6 characters"
      //   ref={ref => {
      //     this._addressinput = ref;
      //   }}
      // onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
      blurOnSubmit={true}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowPassword(showPassword = !showPassword)}>
      <Image
        source={require('./../../../public/icons/Hide.png')}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          right: 0,
          top: -2,
          marginRight: 16,
          // marginTop: 30,
          width: 16,
          height: 16
        }}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</View>
```

But it's not working I am doing something wrong? I think need to do something in state?

Comment: I think the onPress should look like this `setShowPassword(!showPassword)`. You could debug this by setting a console.log with the `showPassword`

Answer (score 0):

the setShowPassword accepts an arrow function as arguments with the state as params

So it should be like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowPassword(showPassword => !showPassword)}>
```